# IPFS Companion - How to NOT load content from my node?

Tags: ipfs, ipfs-companion

If files have been PINNED and I want to test them I need to turn off IPFS Companion
as otherwise files get served from my node. Wondering if I could set it somehow that by default I am not redirected to my node in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in IPFS companion config
"Redirect requests for IPFS resources to your local gateway."

simple, didn't realize it has also preferences, it is on cog wheel of popup in the upper right corner.

[image]